# Problema - Adicionar marcadores do Google Maps a partir de JSON

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, marker

Tou com um problema que é o seguinte: Tenho que fazer uma chamada de um JSON que contém latitude e longitude de diversos locais e adicioná-los, em seguida, em um mapa do Google Maps como marcadores. Consigo carregar tanto o mapa, quanto o JSON, mas os marcadores não são exibidos por um motivo desconhecido. Tipo, o código não apresenta nenhum erro no log do Google Chrome, mas os marcadores não querem aparecer. Alguém sabe como consertar isso? Provavelmente, o erro deve estar na sintaxe, mas não sei aonde...

OBS: O JSON eu não posso mostrar, porque ele não é meu, mas de uma empresa. Mas a estrutura do JSON está correta.

Vejam o código abaixo...

JavaSctipt (jQuery)

```js
// js/gmap_index.js

var mapOptions;
var mapa;
var geocoder;

function CallFirstMap () {
  mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.1634031, -51.1796683),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    scaleControl: true,
    scaleControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
    }
  };
  mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

// js/callPop.js

$(document).ready (function () {
  $.getJSON("my.json", function (data) {
    var marcador, localMarcador;
    $.each(data, function (i, arq) {
      localMarcador = new google.maps.LatLng(arq.lat, arq.long);
      marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapa,
        position: localMarcador
      });
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&callback=CallFirstMap" async defer></script> <!-- coloquei a key como my_key para evitar o uso indevido -->
    <script src="js/gmap_index.js"></script>
```

Comment: No `callPop.js` tente usar um array para adicionar cada marcador, ou seja: `marcadores.push(new google.maps.Marker({"map": mapa, "position": new google.maps.LatLng(arq.lat, arq.long)}));`

Comment: Funcionou. Era erro de referências. Valeu pela ajuda!